# Simple php string issues (HTML and javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am facing problem when print this string it shows error in HTML.
use of comma's are not correct

```
$abc= '$( ".search-fields" ).html("<td colspan="3"><input type="radio" onClick="checkValue("Hotels")" name="type-of-search" value="4"> Hotels </td>");';
```

When I print this, there is error as it print `onClick="checkValue("Hotels")"`.

Comment: Please provide the full code. And use the code sample tool.

Comment: You have not escaped the quotes in your html string

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the quotes in your HTML string

```
$abc= '$( ".search-fields" ).html("<td colspan=\"3\"><input type=\"radio\" onClick=\"checkValue(\\\"Hotels\\\")\" name=\"type-of-search\" value=\"4\"> Hotels </td>");';
```

Comment: This answer is correct.  The amount of escaping involved also indicates that perhaps there is a better way of doing whatever it is the OP is attempting to do.

Answer (score 1):

As roryok mentions in [his correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27980593/1158361) you need escaping.

This is an additional to give some tips on how to improve the readability of the code overal.

If you use jquery you can:

Create Dom elements with readable code with `$('<tag>')` , and customize them with `attr([jsonobject])` or `css([jsonobject])`. Remember you can chain.

Example:

```
var myDiv = $('div')
    .attr({
        id:'foo',
        'name':'bar'
    })
    .css({
        'border':'1px solid #000',
        'margin-top':5
    })
    .on('click', function(){
        alert('clicked');
    });
```

And also easily add an eventhandler on your created DOM element.

This makes everything more readable, and easier to control or change later.

http://jsfiddle.net/w3x8sb07/

```
searchfields = $( ".search-fields" )
table_cell = $('<td>').attr('colspan',3);
radio_button = $('<input>').attr({
    type:'radio',
    name:'type-of-search'
}).val(4);
radio_button.on('click', function(){
    checkValue('Hotels');
});
table_cell.html(radio_button);
searchfields.html(table_cell);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$abc= "$( '.search-fields' ).html('<td colspan=\"3\"><input type=\"radio\" onClick=\"checkValue(\'Hotels\')\" name=\"type-of-search\""
```